# What could be causing a 500 error when deleting data with Spring using http://localhost:8080/delete/1 and how can I resolve it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

in my spring application, i always get the error 500 when i try to delete a data with the request :
http://localhost:8080/delete/1

knowing that i have the data with the id specified and i can get it if i try to access to it with a get method, i still can't understand why my code is not working, i'll let you my controller for more details help me please :

```
@Controller
public class DELETEController {

    @Autowired
    private STBRepository stbRepository;
    
    @DeleteMapping(path = "/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteArtSTB(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        
    if(stbRepository.existsById(id)) {
        stbRepository.deleteById(id);
        return "done";
    }
    else {
         return "you gotta get an error";
    }}}
```

i have tried what was mentioned, i was expecting to see changes and the data deleted from my DB beside the return of the string "done"

Comment: The code looks good. Can you show a stacktrace of error? Could be some problems with the database or configuration in the repo or service

Comment: here is the postman response : 
{
    "timestamp": "2023-05-26T17:17:34.718+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/delete/1"
}
i don't know why but i think it doesn't even execute the function, here is my Repo also : 

public interface STBRepository extends JpaRepository<STB, Long> {
    List<STB> findAll();
}

Comment: here is the stacktrace also : 
2023-05-26T19:26:15.840+02:00 DEBUG 34031 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 400 BAD_REQUEST
2023-05-26T19:26:15.840+02:00 TRACE 34031 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@2f9c6aaa
2023-05-26T19:26:41.882+02:00 DEBUG 34031 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)

Comment: When you attempt to access your controller via PostMan, are you using a DELETE request? If you're doing a GET from PostMan, that would cause the problem.

Comment: Don't know if it is a typo, but I see `@Controller` instead of `@RestController`, while the code seems referring to a rest service.